# css uri skype button

Tags: css, skype

I need to put skype button image inside his div but i am not able to do this.. the only thing that i was able to do is to align the parent div near another div but the skype button image is outside the div.. here the skype code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1" style="border: solid black 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 32px;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "call",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1",
      "participants": ["italy-amo"],
      "imageSize": 32
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

As you can see I used inline css to float the parent div near to another div and that's ok but the image is outside the parent div (id="SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1")..

I tried with css but nothing... I don't know why..

Comment: 1. Can you make a JSfiddle of that? 2. You don't need script inside div - it's probably invalid markup...

Comment: @robjez Why would a script inside a div be invalid?

Comment: @robjez are you so lazy you cannot copy and paste? The OP has provided MVCE, if you want a fiddle, make it yourself!

Comment: @Bramvanroy - is it not? - never seen such construct yet, to be fair - I rather wanted to point out fact, that sticking script tag inside the div will not make "skype" object to appear inside of that element.

Comment: @Pete - I'm that lazy indeed :)

Comment: @robjez [The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

Comment: @BramVanroy - yup, I've just seen that - somehow it just didn't stick to my head. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first thing you can do to make your code perform better is to move script parts -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "call",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1",
      "participants": ["italy-amo"],
      "imageSize": 32
    });
  </script>
```

down and insert it immediately before closing `</body>` tag. Make sure, that order of both scripts is correct.
Then your markup will simply be:

```
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1" style="border: solid black 1px; float:left; height:32px;">
</div>
```

so you can apply following css to adjust it:

```
#SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1_paraElement {
    margin:0;
}
#SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1_paraElement img {
    margin:0 !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

[Here is a JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/pa4m2o9b/) showing that - in the future use it to create working examples of your problem.

**EDIT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
        <style>
            #SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1_paraElement {
                margin:0;
            }
            #SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1_paraElement img {
                margin:0 !important;
                vertical-align:middle !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1" style="border: solid black 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 32px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Skype.ui({
              "name": "call",
              "element": "SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1",
              "participants": ["italy-amo"],
              "imageSize": 32
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for my late reply... I did as you suggested and when i load the page i have this message: "Sorry! Could not find Skype URI parent element: SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1 ('SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1')"..

How can I fix this?

Comment: You must have mispelled either `div's` id or `Skype.ui` `element` value in script. They both must match. Show me your code, so I have a look on this. I also attach full working example as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks it was my fault, your example is right, i did a copy and paste and it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to go with this css and code then please go with this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>test</title>
    <style>
        .skyype{border: solid black 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 32px; display:flex;}
        #SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1_paraElement {margin:0px !important;padding:0px !important;}
        .skyype img {margin:0px !important; vertical-align:0px !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1" class="skyype"> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "call",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_italy-amo_1",
      "participants": ["italy-amo"],
      "imageSize": 32
    });
  </script>
```

but please read back..it is quick around according to your code but i will suggest you to go with simple html structure.sorry if m doing anything wrong..ty